# asp.net mvc area default page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have a MVC 2 site with an area, let's say the area name is {Admin}

The areas and the site works fine.

What I am trying to do is to have different default page for the area.

When I am calling **http://webSiteName** works with no problem

but for **http://webSiteName/Admin** I am getting the error

> The resource cannot be found

I tried it out the solutions from [ASP.NET MVC 2 RC 2 returns Area-specific controller when no area specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314524/asp-net-mvc-2-rc-2-returns-area-specific-controller-when-no-area-specified)
but with no luck.

I tried also

```
routes.MapRoute(
                 "Admin",                                         
                 "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                               
                 new { controller = "AdminHome", action = "index" },
                 new[] { "Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
                 );
```

and

```
routes.MapRoute(
                 "Admin",                                      
                 "Admin",                              
                 new { controller = "AdminHome", action = "index" },   
                 new string[] { "Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
                 );
```

but I am still  getting **The resource cannot be found.**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please mark the anser as accepted if it helped you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this. Make sure it will be in `/Areas/Admin/AdminAreaRegistration.cs` when your Area is named `Admin`.

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "AdminHome",action = "Index", id = "" }
        );
    }
```

You don't have to add anything to your `Global.asax`.

Comment: Thanks Martin, finally it was easier than I thought.
:)