# Routing to an Area home page in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, areas

I'm trying to route to the home page of an Area in MVC, e.g.

```
myDomain.com/myArea/Home/Index
```

when I use the URL:

```
myDomain.com/myArea
```

MVC appears to by trying to find a Controller called "myArea" in the root Controllers folder and thereby would route to:

```
myDomain.com/myArea/Index
```

if the Controller existed.

Again, I want:

```
myDomain.com/myArea
```

to route to:

```
myDomain.com/myArea/Home/Index
```

I figure that I should be able to do this in Global.asax without having to resort to creating a dummy controller that re-routes to the area controller, but I've drawn a blank.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298325/asp-net-mvc-area-default-page

Answer (score 0):

One way I used to get around this was to set the namespaces property on the default route in the Global RegisterRoutes method, this seemed to resolve that problem. Had to add this restriction to some other routes where I had conflicts between Controller in the main website and the area.

```
var namespaces = new[] { "CompiledExperience.Website.Web.Controllers" };

routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces
);
```

Comment: Yes, I already tried that, but it made no difference.  I made sure I restarted IIS to ensure that the routes were re-registered.  Thanks though.

Comment: MooseFactory did you figure this one out?. i have the same issue